# Описать рекурсивную функцию MaxInt(A, N) целого типа, которая находит максимальный элем

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Описать рекурсивную функцию MaxInt(A, N) целого типа, которая находит максимальный элемент целочисленного массива A размера N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10), не используя оператор цикла. С помощью этой функции найти максимальные элементы массивов A, B, C размера NA, NB, NC соответственно.
Все исправил в функции. Вопрос следующий. Мне нужно функцию использоавть для нескольких массив. Но так как max статик, то выдает во всех массивах максимальный элемент один и тот же. Как исправить?

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int MaxInt(int A[], int N);//Обьявление функции.
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int size;
    cout << "Введите количество элеметнов массива от 1 до 10 :  " ;
    cin >> size;
    if (size < 1 || size>10)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int Array_A[10];
    int Array_B[10];
    int Array_C[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Array_A[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    cout << "Массив 1" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << Array_A[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Array_B[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    cout << "Массив 2" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << Array_B[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Array_C[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    cout << "Массив 3" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << Array_C[i] << "\t";
    }
    MaxInt(Array_A, size);
    MaxInt(Array_B, size);
    MaxInt(Array_C, size);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nMax 1 = " << MaxInt(Array_A, size) << endl;
    cout << "\nMax 2= " << MaxInt(Array_B, size) << endl;
    cout << "\nMax 3= " << MaxInt(Array_C, size) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int MaxInt(int A[], int N)
{
    static int max = 0;
    if (N > 0)
    {
        if (A[N - 1] > max)
        {
            max = A[N - 1];
        }
        return MaxInt(A, N - 1);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Можно начать с того, что Вы используете очень странный заголовок у функции `int main(int num_elements, int *Array_A)`. Есть подозрение, что компилятор Вам об этом пытался сказать, но Вы же его игнорируете. И второе: у массива размером `N` нет элемента `A[N]` - нумерация индексов начинается с 0 и заканчивается на `N-1`. В итоге, Ваша программа - одно сплошное неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Очень много неопределённостей.1) У вас массив передаётся через аргументы в мейн, как и количество элементов, тогда зачем вы снова считываете их количество? 2) Зачем так  вычурно искать максимальный элемент, а если массив состоит только из отрицательных чисел, тогда максимальным будет 0. 3) В массиве максимальный индекс, как было замечено, имеет номер n-1,  а у вас при вызове функции MaxInt он равен n.

Comment: Изменил программу, посмотрите еше раз пожалуйста

Comment: Вам надо передавать в функцию в качестве параметра ранее найденный максимум и сравнивать текущий последний элемент с ним. `int MaxInt (int A[], int n, int curmax) { if (n > 0)  curmax = MaxInt(A, n - 1, curmax < A[n - 1] ? A[n - 1] : curmax); return curmax;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вы возвращаете из функции максимум.. куда? в смысле, присвойте его чему-то или хотя бы сразу же выведите, типа `cout << "\nMax = " << MaxInt(Array_A, size) << endl;`
2. При каждом рекурсивном запуске функции Ваш `max` равен 0. Если хотите, чтобы максимальное значение сохранялось между вызовами, то нужно объявить эту переменную как статическую:

   ```
    int MaxInt(int A[], int N)
    {
        static int max = 0;
        if (N > 0)
        {
            if (A[N - 1] > max) { 
                max = A[N - 1]; 
            }
            return MaxInt(A, N - 1);
        }
        return max;
    }
   ```

UPD: в связи с уточнением задачи и ограничением на прототип рекурсивной функции привожу второй вариант с использованием грубой силы в лице глобальной переменной:

вне всех функций объявляется глобальная `int max`, после чего рекурсивная функция будет:

```
    int MaxInt(int A[], int N)
    {
        if (N > 0)
        {
            if (A[N - 1] > max) { 
                max = A[N - 1]; 
            }
            return MaxInt(A, N - 1);
        }
        return max;
    }
```

И после каждого вызова функции перед вызовом для нового массива необходимо "сбрасывать" эту глобальную переменную `max=0;`.

UPD2: как верно подметил @avp, значениями массива могут быть и только отрицательные числа. И в таком случае, за начальное значение `max` лучше принимать какой-то элемент каждого массива, например, первый: `max = Array_A[0]`.

Comment: Да, все понял, все исправил. Новый вопрос мне эту функцию нужно применить для трех массивов, но так как max имеет статик, то для всех выдает один и тот же максимум как исправить?

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович, в этом случае проще сделать как советует в комментарии avp: передавать максимум в функцию как входной параметр, а не делать его статической переменной. Тогда для каждого нового массива можно этот параметр обнулять снаружи функции.

Comment: У меня в условии задания функция состоит только из двух переменных

Comment: я делал уже с несколькими,работа была опровергнута, со словами, если вас возьмут на работу и скажут сделать то то и то то, а вы сделаете по своиму

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович, сделать по-своему - не всегда плохо ;-). Вообще, лучше сразу указывать полное условие задачи, а не мелкими порциями - так больше шансов получить правильный ответ сразу. Если надо функцию только с двумя параметрами... А там указано с какими именно? потому как вторым параметром можно сделать и структуру, содержащую все необходимое :-). И... очевидный вариант с глобальной переменной вместо статической тоже не подойдет (хотя это плохое решение)?

Comment: Описать рекурсивную функцию MaxInt(A, N) целого типа, которая находит максимальный элемент целочисленного массива A размера N (1 ≤ N ≤ 10), не используя оператор цикла. С помощью этой функции найти максимальные элементы массивов A, B, C размера NA, NB, NC соответственно.

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович, вроде здесь не вижу никаких ограничений на использование глобальной переменной. Тогда объявление статической переменной `max` убирайте из функции, а перед функцией `main()` объявите глобальную `int max`. Ну и между вызовами для разных массивов очищайте этот `max`.

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович, кстати, размеры массивов в задаче следует считать разными - к этому тоже могут быть претензии ;-).

Comment: то есть для каждого массива вводить разное количесвто элементов?

Comment: @ДаниилМартынович, ну, можно попробовать и так отдать, но быть готовым вставить еще пару `cin >> size;` с приглашениями перед заданием этих массивов (так то максимальный размер указан явно и один для всех).

Comment: большое спасибо все получилось

Comment: `max = 0` --- что будет, если все элементы массива меньше нуля?

Comment: @avp, при данном методе генерации значений массивов они не будут меньше нуля. Но да, в общем случае лучше брать первый элемент каждого массива за начальное значение.